Usual price of MRAM compared to other non-volatile memories
I was researching MRAM and I saw that a 64 megabit MRAM chip was $64. What are the usual prices of MRAM per megabyte? Are there any other technologies with unlimited read/write endurance that are cheaper?

Hard disks or magnetic tape have pretty much unlimited rewrite endurance and are cheaper per Mb.  Vtc, because shopping question

The question is a bit odd. MRAM does not have unlimited writes. So an answer would need to factor in the unlimited writes and also cheaper. Will battery backed-up SRAM be unlimited enough?
